# youtu.be links in chat don't have previews generated

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks

The Stack Exchange chat recognizes links you youtube.com and generates a preview. Links to YouTube's shorter domain for sharing (youtu.be) don't get a preview generated.

Comment: I believe you meant to post here: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77/chat-feedback

Comment: @drachenstern I got pointed here. Also, "The last message was posted 13 days ago." But thanks for the link; I'll post there too.

Comment: lol, I'm sorry to hear that Nathan. I was kinda being a smartass, but I also figured it was good to post that here too.

Comment: Posting here on meta is fine. Don't listen to @drachenstern, he's a troublemaker!

Comment: @balpha I did acknowledge I was being sassy ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been meaning to make that work for a while now; thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: There we go. All better. Thanks!